# How to give Argument like (-s) in custom action properties of Setup project in VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment

I have a setup project and i want to execute another application at the end of my setup so that second application can install drivers and certificates.

In this matter, I am using Custom Actions. In Custom action am using Commit folder and added an action that works fine. But the problem is that i want to execute second application with command line argument. There is a property of argument but am unable to find a way to provide argument.

Comment: have you tried to run the exe file in CMD you can include parameters there

Comment: Do you have a _good_ reason for still using VS2010 in 2023?